# How to use gdata-objectivec-client?

Tags: objective-c, ios, gdata-api, gdata-objectivec-client

I followed the steps in this [tutorial](http://hoishing.wordpress.com/2011/08/23/gdata-objective-c-client-setup-in-xcode-4/). Now I can import the header file of youtube libraries to my class but I don't know how to use them. For instance, How to login to youtube and add a video to favorite list? Please give me some sample code since I am really new in objective-c and gdata-objectivec-client.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you followed a tutorial just for setting up the library.
I find one about using GData here:

http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/wiki/GDataObjCIntroduction

Comment: do you want to upload the video to youtube from your app?

Comment: I want to add a video with specified VIDEO_ID to my favorite list